# Why is the update operation not posting any data?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the Kendo Grid with inline editing. When I click the "Update" button, a POST gets made to my controller method with this signature. The controller action gets hit, so the POST is working.

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SaveAccountAdmin(string jsonCompanyContacts)
```

However the POST data in the update operation never arrives - its always null.

```
update: {
              url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                  jsonCompanyContacts: "John Doe"
              }
          },
```

Here is the FULL data source code.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
  {
      batch: false,
      pageSize: 10,

      transport: {
          create: {
              url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json"
          },

          read: {
              url: "/Company/ReadAccountAdmin"
          },

          update: {
              url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              data: {
                  jsonCompanyContacts: "John Doe"
              }
          },
          //destroy: {},

          parameterMap: function (data, type) {
              return kendo.stringify(data);
          }
      },
```

this doesnt work either:

```
update: {
              url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              //data: { "jsonCompanyContacts": kendo.stringify({ jsonCompanyContacts: "John Doe" }) }

              data: { "jsonCompanyContacts": "John Doe" }
          },
          //destroy: {},

          parameterMap: function (data, type) {
              return kendo.stringify(data);
          }
```

BUT THIS WORKS- WHY?

```
update: {
              url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              //data: { "jsonCompanyContacts": kendo.stringify({ jsonCompanyContacts: "John Doe" }) }

              //data: { "jsonCompanyContacts": "John Doe" }
          },
          //destroy: {},

          parameterMap: function (data, type) {
              return kendo.stringify({ "jsonCompanyContacts": "John Doe" });
          }
```

Comment: Oh - and I am using jQuery 1.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is not passed to the controller as a string.  Try using a model.  This might help: [MVC3 & JSON.stringify() ModelBinding returns null model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597892/mvc3-json-stringify-modelbinding-returns-null-model)

#### UPDATE

You really don't want to do it like that.  Might work in theis one case, but you are shooting yourself in the foot.

Model

```
public class CompanyContactModel
{
    public string CompanyContacts { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Signature

```
public JsonResult SaveAccountAdmin(CompanyContactModel companyContactModel)
...
```

Better

```
public JsonResult SaveAccountAdmin([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, CompanyContactModel companyContactModel)
    ...
    Update and Return and put into List
    If error: ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, e.Message);

    DataSourceResult result = [Your Model List].ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hey Trey - can you be more specific please? surely the return kendo.stringify(data) is sending a string (albeit a json string)?

Comment: MVC controllers can accept JSON models as actual models; you don't have to parse them in as a string. Alter your controller to accept a model that matches the format of the JSON you're sending.

Comment: @anaximander - thanks for the reply. What would my model(signature) in the action method look like? Could you give me a basic example with FirstName, LastName.

Comment: I am close to solving this. Can anyone tell me how to pass the grid data to the parameterMap? model doesnt work.

Comment: Im not using Kendo MVC so I dont have DataSourceRequest. I dont understand how I can send json formatted data into a CompanyContactModel object.Doesnt it have to be deserialized first? So now my controller signature looks like [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult EditAccountAdmin(List<CompanyContact> jsonCompanyContacts). Now the problem is getting the parameterMap to send the grid data. Been searching for hours. Nothing

Comment: Actually - I'm not close to solving anything. 1 step forward = 10 steps back. The tickets I have raised have a 48 hour SLA. None have been answered yet. This just isn't a viable product to use in a production scenario. Thanks everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in your update definition:

```
  update: {
      url: "/Company/SaveAccountAdmin",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data:{ "jsonCompanyContacts":  kendo.stringify({ jsonCompanyContacts: "John Doe"  })}
      }
```

You might have to remove the operation in your parameterMap for this to work. The main thing is that you want to post a variable with the **same name** as in your controller. That variable should contain your stringified data.

You could also move this operation to your parameterMap if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Logard. I tried your code leaving in the parameter map (because I think inline editing needs it) and it didn't work. The data is still null. I then commented out the parameter map and the POST doesn't happen.

Comment: I also tried allowing the parameter map to stringify the data(See my update). Still null..

Comment: Thanks Logard - one of your suggestions worked. I just dont know why :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem like you.I am getting values from the broswer , but its not posting the values to the update action model.

In my case I used "[ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]" on the model which works fine.